# Possible to filter a queryset by its ForeignKey related_name objects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a simple model:

```
class Object(models.Model):
  name = CharField()
  root = ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

I create a few objects:

```
parent1 = Object.create(name="parent1")
o1 = Object.create(name="1", root=parent1")

parent1.object_set.all() # Returns queryset with o1
```

Is it possible to filter a queryset by its ForeignKey's related_name objects (i.e. `object_set`)? Something like:

```
Object.objects.filter(object_set__name="1") # To return parent1
```

I get the following error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'object_set' into field.`

I understand I could do `Object.object.get(name="1").root` but that results in additional queries which could really add up in my specific use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Object.objects.filter(object__name="1")`
```

instead of:

```
Object.objects.filter(object_set__name="1")
```

How to determine the lookup name is described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships-1):

> While it [can be customized](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name), by default you refer to a “reverse” relationship in a lookup using the lowercase name of the model.